# Show that ${n\choose k}\leq 2^n$

Tags: induction

Show that ${n\choose k}\leq 2^n$ for all naturals with $0\leq k \leq n $.I know I need to use induction and for the base case $n=1$ what exactly am I showing?

Comment: The base case is $n=0$.

Comment: Without induction: for $n$ fixed, what is the sum over $k$ of all the ${n\choose k}$ already?

Answer (score 6):

Since
$$
2^n=(1+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k},
$$
it follows that
$$
{n\choose k} \le 2^n\quad \forall k=0,1,\ldots,n.
$$

Answer (score 4):

Think about what the two terms mean. ${n \choose k}$ is the number of ways that you can choose $k$ elements out of a pack of $n$; $2^n$ is the size of the power set of $\{1,...,n\}$, in particular the number of ways that you can choose $r$ out of $n$, *for any* $r$. Thus clearly the first is a subset of the second, so the number of ways is less than or equal to.

Hope this helps give some motivation for why this is true! :)

Answer (score 0):

For $n=0$, $\binom 00 \le 2^0$.

Assume $\binom nk \le 2^n$ for an $n\ge 0$ and for all $0\le k\le n$.

Consider $\binom {n+1}k$. If $k=0$ or $k = n+1$, then $\binom{n+1}k = 1 < 2^{n+1}$.

Otherwise, $\binom{n+1}k = \binom n{k-1} + \binom nk \le 2^n + 2^n = 2^{n+1}$.

Comment: How are you getting your last line? Clearly you can apply the inductive hypothesis to $\binom{n}{k}$, but how are you concluding that $\binom{n}{k-1}\leq2^n$? We clearly don't have $\binom{n}{k-1}\leq\binom{n}{k}$ (consider $n=10, k=6$ a counterexample).

Comment: He has assumed that $\binom nk \le 2^n$ **for all* $0 \le k \le n$; ie, he's doing induction on $n$, assuming the result for all $k$. (Also, for your (correct) counterexample at the end, just consider $k = n > 1$ and it holds - or just any $k > \text{ceil}(n/2)$.) :)